# Upgrade CE1.4 to 1.5 Version

Tags: upgrade, magento-connect

I need to upgrade 1.4.0.2 to 1.5.x.I'm following steps mentioned in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662347/how-to-upgrade-magento-1-4-1-1-to-1-7-0-2)

Everything is going fine. But after passing the command

```
./mage config-set preferred_state stable
```

version 1.7.* becomes the stable state.

**UPDATE**

Now upgrading from 1.5 to 1.6 version is not working.

Comment: If you are really on 1.4, the CLI tool should still be called `pear` instead of `mage`?

Comment: After running `./pear upgrade -f magento-core/Mage_All_Latest-stable` `mage` tool works

Comment: Why exactly 1.5? There were some major changes between 1.4 and 1.5 so I assume backwards compatibility with old extensions can't be the reason.

Comment: @blakcaps: Are you under version control?

Comment: Not using version control

Comment: Could you solve your problem? Please share your solution or mark one of the answer as solution. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to install the version 1.5 instead of 1.7 (which fixes at least two security problems) then you can just download the version:

wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.5.1.0/magento-1.5.1.0.tar.gz

And copy it over.

But you know, check for core hacks before. Or you may loose functionality.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99/how-do-you-give-estimates-for-magento-upgrade? has good reference on checking for core hacks and evaluating code before an upgrade. I wouldn't use the `./mage` or `./pear` tools but just like Fabian mentioned just copy the new code over the old, after backing up first. :)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it could be related to the address, city or zip code you are entering.

Some carriers don't ship to specific addresses.

You can test this out by going to http://postcalc.usps.com/ and entering the same data you would in Magento.

Also make sure your `Store Information` is fully entered, as some carriers will use this to provide estimates.

Go to `System > Configuration > General` and fill out `Store Information`.