# Strange arrays being output on front-end instead of website

Tags: php, array, varien

Trying to setup version control on a pre-existing client's site. There have been a number of developers who have had their hands in this and I'm slowly modifying the .gitignore file in attempt to bring over all the necessary files. It's a real mess but somehow running in production. :D

I'm currently getting an array output on my front-end that is something like this repeated about 50 times on my local environment:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => /Users/deeperdata/Documents/webroot/website/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php [line] => 96 [function] => _connect [class] => Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract [type] => -> [args] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] =>
```

I checked Apache, PHP and Magento logs. I'm showing nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really looks like some `var_dump/print_r` output left by one of the previous developers.

You are in quite a bad situation as you don't even know if there are any core hacks. So I think your main talk is not to get any output but to cleanup the installation. And you will definitely solve this "arrays" issue in the process.

I would suggest to start with detecting core hacks. You can find them by referring to "In-Core Modifications" section of my answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99/how-do-you-give-estimates-for-magento-upgrade/114#114).

Then you can try reverting to default theme and disabling 3rd party modules one-by-one. You will definitely locate your issue in process.