# Upgrade Magento from 1.3.1 to 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-1.3

I need to upgrade a Magento store from 1.3.1 to the latest version of Magento (1.9.1). Can anybody point me in the right direction on the best way to do this.

Are there certain versions numbers you need to upgrade to due to major changes or can I upgrade directly to 1.9.1?

Any help would be great!

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99/how-do-you-give-estimates-for-magento-upgrade

Comment: @Daniel From 1.3.1 to 1.4 and from 1.7 to 1.8 can be considered major changes. If your site do not have too many customizations you should not face major issues.But personally I won't recommend to upgrade directly from 1.3.1 to 1.9.1

Comment: @Muk Yes there are customisations that I don't know about which will need to be worked on. If I upgrade through these versions I should be OK? Then it's just extensions and the theme to work on.

Comment: Those customizations will have to be reviewed, altered. You are jumping 6 major version releases, so it is very unlikely those will work right off the bat.

Comment: @kab8609 I expect that all the current extensions won't work but we should be able to replace them. It's mainly the core magento files and database that i'm more concerned about.

Comment: Yeah, anything that was changed in the core will be gone. In fact, if you are going to 1.9, you actually should just start on a new code instance (this is what Magento recommends).

Comment: @kab8609 A new code instance? As in a fresh Magento installation? The main problem with that is keeping all of the existing data from the current site.

Comment: Yeah, take a clean copy of 1.9 and then attempt the upgrade using your existing database. Your data exists in the database, not the code. Remember to do this on a staging site, not the live.