# How to upgrade Magento from 1.5 to 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-1.5

Anyone could give me some tips how I upgrade Magento 1.5 to 1.9? I am new in Magento and I didn't see any upgrade option in my Magento backend.

Answer (score 0):

Updating a Magento shop can be a complex task, especially if you have custom code and/or lots of extensions. Take a look at [How do you give estimates for Magento upgrade?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/99/243) to get an idea.

Bottom line is, don't do it, if you are new to Magento development. Hire somebody with experience and don't be surprised if it gets expensive.

**Exception:** if your shop has *no modifications* and *no custom theme* (i.e. only 3rd party themes/extensions), you can download the latest version from http://magentocommerce.com/download, get the latest version for all your extensions, the latest version for your theme and hope for the best.

**Important: Don't ever do this directly on a production server!**

Comment: I am not sure if 'don't do it', 'hire someone' and 'hope for the best' are constructive answers to this question.

Comment: The alternative is to close the question as "Too broad".

Comment: You can try below command line trick to upgrade your current setup into latest version:

chmod 550 mage
./mage mage-setup .

./mage config-set preferred_state stable

./mage sync

./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force

php shell/indexer.php reindexall

rm -rf downloader/.cache/ var/cache/

Let us know if this work.